# How to bind YES image for multiple selectable custom list

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to create an imagelist in which i can select muliple items, I have one yes icon that I want to set visible for whatever items i select(*like checkbox*) and invisible on unselect... I have added image into xml file and set its `visibility as GONE`(as it should not be visible initially).. Please tell me possible solutions..

for the list I have set   `list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`

And my custom `BaseAdapter` class contains,

```
public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image,yesimage;
    public TextView quantity;        
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.quantity=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.quantity);     
        holder.yesimage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.selectedyes);        
        vi.setTag(holder);


    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();  

   // Here I wanted to know how can i set visibility of yesimege for individual    selected items on list

    holder.text.setText(items[position]);
    holder.image.setTag(data[position]);
    holder.quantity.setText(Integer.toString(qty[position]).trim());

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, holder.image);
    return vi;
}
```

xml snippet item.xml

```
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image"
  android:layout_width="50dip"
  android:layout_height="50dip" 
  android:src="@drawable/stub" 
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/text"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1" 
  android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" 
  android:textSize="15dip" 
  android:typeface="sans"
      android:textColor="#000000"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>

    <TextView
  android:id="@+id/quantity"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1" 
  android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" 
  android:gravity="right"
  android:paddingRight="10dp"
  android:textSize="18dip" 
  android:typeface="sans"
      android:textColor="#000000"/>


         <ImageView android:id="@+id/selectedyes" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/itemselected" 
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip" 
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" ></ImageView> 

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing in doing so?

Comment: See there is a base list updated by server and there is sublist called cart, on click of baselist item it goes to cart list, everything is working fine but in base list there is no indicator to show already selected items.. I want to display yes image on every selected items of baselist just for indication..

Answer (score 0):

You have to save/store that your item is selected or not.
After that check if the item is selected or not and use one of the following:

```
holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE); // to make it disappear
```

or

```
holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // to display it
```

---

I don't know exactly what's in your data array, but you can save the state there.

```
if (data[position].isVisible()) {
    holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // to display it
else
    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE); // to make it disappear
```

---

You can catch click events with setting an [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) on your ListView.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Put your custom code here
        }
 });
```

Does it answer your question?